# Как сделать на сайте метки тегов

Tags: php, mysql

Я не знаю с чего начать вижу на сайтах такую ерунду и тоже хочу сделать(сайты:http://hashcode.ru http://www.rudebox.org.ua/)
хотелось бы сбоку поставить и к новости прикрутить

Comment: все будет понятно если посмотрите эти два сайта

Comment: Что именно тебе хочется поставить как на сайте "хеш код"? Дай ссылку на свой сайт для оценки.


Comment: не могу я еще его не сделал

Comment: к примеру да

Comment: к каждому вопросу есть определенные метки вот я также хочу сделать
ну и соответсвенно чтобы можно было кликать по ним и переходить с этим результатом

Comment: вот картинка http://imageshack.us/f/210/23609220.png/

Comment: Не, ну я еще понимаю, если вопрос выглядит как "объясните принципы работы облака тегов"... Но когда вопрос выглядит настолько абстрактно, у меня возникает ощущение, что ТС просит сделать за него работу. Да еще и указывает, как должен отображаться результат. =)

Answer (score 1):

Не буду писать весь код, подскажу **запрос**, иначе, если всё всегда будут делать за вас, вы ничему не научитесь

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `tags` LIKE '% $MY_SEARCH_TAG %'
,где
table - таблица
tags - колонка таблицы, где записаны теги каждой записи
$MY_SEARCH_TAG - переменная, из запроса (необходимый тег)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так реализовывал, ну конечно у меня в CMS, сложнее реализовано c mysql, думаю прикрутить этот код к mysql вы сможете:

```
$tags = array('php','html','php','css','javascript','php','html','php');
$tags = array_count_values($tags);
$i ='0';
foreach($tags as $tag = > $num) {
$i = $i+1;
if($i == max($tags)) {
echo '<a href="#">'.$tag.'</a> <sup>'.$num.'</sup>';
} else {
echo '<a href="#">'.$tag.'</a> <sup>'.$num.'</sup>, ';
}
}
```

Comment: Самое бредовое решение получившее голос "ЗА", простите конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если по простому, то сделать можно примерно так:

```
-- таблица тегов
create table tag (
    id  int primary key auto_index,
    tag text not null
)
-- таблица связка теги <-> статьи
create table tag_article (
    tag_id int not null,
    article_id in not null,
    primary key (tag_id, article_id)
)
-- таблица статей
create table article (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    --  все прочие поля
)
```

Собственно запрос всех статей с одним указанным тегом:

```
select
    a.*
from article a
    left join tag_article ta on (a.id = ta.artice_id)
    left join tag t on (t.id = ta.tag_id)
where
    t.tag = 'html'
```

Запрос всех статей с несколькими указанными тегами. Для более простого понимания процесса понимаем что у нас есть:

```
$need_tags = array('php','mysql');
```

путем запроса к таблице `tags` получаем:

```
$need_tags_id = array(13,15);
```

Собственно запрос:

```
select
    a.*
from article 1
   left join tag_article t on (a.id = t.article_id)
where
   t.tag_id in (13,15)
group by
   a.id
having
   count(t.id) = 2 -- count($need_tags_id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Нашел вот такой скрипт но на строчке "`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_p))` " выводит ошибку `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in`

```
<?php

/* Скрипт для создания простейшего облака тегов. 
Для его работы необходима таблица MySQL: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
CREATE TABLE `tag` ( 
  `tag` text NOT NULL, 
  `counter` varchar(5) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Пиво', '323'); 
INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Водка', '424'); 
INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Коньяк', '160'); 
INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Ликер', '127'); 
INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Настойка', '95'); 
INSERT INTO `tag` VALUES ('Спирт', '153'); 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Для правильного отображения облака на странице  
необходима примерно такая таблица стилей: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
<style> 
#tagcloud { 
    width: 300px; 
    background:#FFF; 
    padding: 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    text-align:center; 
}

#tagcloud span { 
    padding: 4px; 
}

.smallest { 
    font-size: x-small; 
}

.small { 
    font-size: small; 
}

.medium { 
    font-size:medium; 
}

.large { 
    font-size:large; 
}

.largest { 
    font-size:larger; 
} 
</style> 
----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password') OR DIE("Нет соединения с базой."); 
mysql_select_db("base") OR DIE("Не могу выбрать базу.");  
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");   //  нужно подключиться к базе!

$terms = array(); // создали массив 
$maximum = 0; // переменная для рассчёта максимального значения

$query = "SELECT tag, counter FROM `tag`"; // в таблице - теги и число использований. Выбираем.

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{ 
    $tag = $row['tag']; 
    $counter = $row['counter']; 
    if ($counter> $maximum) $maximum = $counter; // обновляем максимум. В таблице не должно быть нулей. 
    $terms[] = array('tag' => $tag, 'counter' => $counter); // добавляем в массив 
}

shuffle($terms);  // перемешиваем массив, если нужно.

echo "<div id='tagcloud'><div>\n"; // начинаем вывод облака 
foreach ($terms as $k) // бежим по тегам в массиве 
{

    $percent = floor(($k['counter'] / $maximum) * 100);  // рассчёт популярности тега в процентах

    // определяем класс для тега из его популярности 
    if ($percent <20) 
    { 
        $class = 'smallest'; 
    } elseif ($percent>= 20 and $percent <40) { 
        $class = 'small'; 
    } elseif ($percent>= 40 and $percent <60) { 
        $class = 'medium'; 
    } elseif ($percent>= 60 and $percent <80) { 
        $class = 'large'; 
    } else { 
        $class = 'largest'; 
    }

    // выводим тег 
    echo "<span class='$class'><a href='tag.php?q=" . urlencode($k['tag']) . "' title='" . $k['tag'] . "'>" . $k['tag'] . "</a></span>\n "; 
    // здесь tag.php - страница, на которую создаются ссылки из облака. 
} 
echo "</div></div><br />\n";
```

Comment: вот что мне надо <p><img src='http://imageshack.us/f/210/23609220.png/'><p>

Comment: ЕСТЕСТВЕННО он выведет ошибку!

    $query = "SELECT tag, counter FROM `tag`";

Что за бред! Где сам запрос к БД

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT tag, counter FROM `tag`");

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,author,link
                       FROM 'topik", $db);
$myrow  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

do {
    printf("<table align='center' class='programs '>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p class='news_adds'>№: %s</p>
    <p class='news_adds'>автор статьи: %s</p>
    <a class='link_1' href='view_topik.php?id=%s'>просмотр <img src='img/pic/ref.gif' width='16' height='16' alt='смотреть подробности' border=0></a></font> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table></p><br><br>", $myrow["id"], $myrow["author"], $myrow["link"]);

} while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
?>
```

Comment: Данным кодом можно выводить весь топиковый список из базы MySql. Если не разобрался - пиши.

Comment: Это я так понимаю new-OMFG-REAL-SUCK-school писать printf в сочетании с `do .. while`? Секта чтоле? О_о

Comment: ухаха))) я теперь только while юзаю

Comment: не так он должен при нажатии на тег скачать результаты связанные с ним